# Sending anonymous actions using UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction in Swift 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I have been using `sendAction` method with `nil` `target` to communicate actions from `Cells(UITableViewCell/UICollectionViewCell)` to `ViewControllers`, instead of implementing a delegate.

Since Swift 2.2 the syntax for selector has been updated and I get some warning. The new `#selector` syntax insists on specifying the `selectorname` followed by `classname`. If I mention the class name then there is no meaning in setting the target to nil.

Any workaround for this?

```
    class RedeemCell: UICollectionViewCell { 
    @IBAction func redeemAction(sender: AnyObject) {                 
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("updateCartWithTotalAmountPayableWithDiscount:", to: nil, from: self, forEvent: nil)
        } 
    }

class CartVC: UIViewController {

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell: UICollectionViewCell?

            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("redeempoints", forIndexPath: indexPath)


        return cell!;
    }

func updateCartWithTotalAmountPayableWithDiscount(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("this will be called as the action movies through responderchain and encounters this method");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share come code to explain how you have been using it so far?

Comment: @rptwsthi updated the question with code

Comment: Yes I just checked it, unfortunately I have no workaround for this. May be someone come for rescue. Good Luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can (and probably should) pass `#selector(CartVC.updateCartWithTotalAmountPayableWithDiscount)`. When you do this, you're saying that you want a selector for the `updateCart...` function that the `CartVC` class defines — as opposed to the `updateCart...` function defined by some other class.

This is different from the meaning of passing `nil` as your target — the class you name in the `#selector` expression clarifies *what* the message you want to send is, based on the class that defines it. The target is about *who* you send the message *to*. When you choose nil for the target, you're saying the message should go to the first object that can handle it — which could be one of several instances of `CartVC`, or an instance of another class that accepts the same message.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Selector()` to create a selector from a string in Objective-C style. To avoid a warning saying "Use #selector", use a parameter to store the selector name and pass it to `Selector()` instead of passing a string literal directly.

```
let selectorName = "updateCartWithTotalAmountPayableWithDiscount:"
UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(Selector(selectorName), to: nil, from: self, forEvent: nil)
```

Comment: Or you can put an extra parentheses around the string: `Selector(("updateCartWithTotalAmountPayableWithDiscount:"))`

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `sendAction` for this, instead of using something like `NSNotificationCenter`?

Comment: I could have used delegate or NSNotificationCenter had the sendAction could not achieve the requirement. My doubt is that, with the new syntax we would never be able to use sendAction in the way i did above.

Comment: Given that it doesn't work in the way you did above with sendAction, maybe now is time to reconsider your past decisions and use the right way of dealing with it instead?

Comment: NSNotificationCenter is for broadcasting events down the hierarchy. sendAction (and delegation) is for sending events up the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

A little too late for this but now you should define a protocol that is visible to the objective-c runtime and use that protocol. I guess UITableViewDelegate seems more beautiful now, doesn't it? :)